# There is no filesystem disk named public

Tags: laravel, media-library

```
$user->addMedia($request->file('avatar'))->toMediaCollection();
```

error: There is no filesystem disk named public in DiskDoesNotExist.php line 11

How to Fix Please Help from 2 day trying to fix..
Issue Posted on Github also but not help anyone
[Github Issue](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/1478)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the collection name as parameter inside `toMediaCollection()`
like below

```
$user->addMedia($request->file('avatar'))->toMediaCollection('avatar');
```